# Does MATLAB have any set-like datatype?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, set, primitive-types, custom-data-type

I am looking for a way to compare finite sequential data with non-deterministic ordering in MATLAB. Basically, what I want is an array, but without imposing an order on the contained elements. If I have the objects

```
a = [x y z];
```

and

```
b = [x z y];
```

I'd want `isequal(a, b)` to return true. With arrays, this is not the case. The easy fix would be to sort the entries before comparing them. Unfortunately, in my case the elements are complex objects which cannot easily be mapped to have an unambigious numerical relationship to each other. Another approach would be not to use `isequal`, but rather a custom comparison function which asserts matching lengths and then simply checks if each element from the first array is contained in the second one. However, in my case the arrays are non-trivially nested inside the structs I am trying to compare via `isequal`, and it would be quite complicated to write a custom comparison function for the encapsulating structs. Other than this ordering problem, the inbuilt `isequal` function covers all of my needs, as it correctly handles arbitrarily nested structs with arbitrary fields, so I would really like to avoid writing a complicated custom function for that.

Is there any datatype in MATLAB which allows for the described behavior? Or is there a way to easily build such a custom type? In Java, I could simply write a wrapper class with a custom implementation for the `equals` method, but there seems to be no such mechanism in MATLAB?

Comment: If `isequal` suits your needs except for order, can't you do somthing like?: `a = {[20 20 30], 'abc', {[1 2]; [3:4]}}; b = a; [aa, bb] = ndgrid(a, a); m = arrayfun(@isequal, aa, bb), result = all(any(m,1))&all(any(m,2))` It follows your idea of testing each element in one array against each element in the other (via calls to `isequal`), which may be time-inefficient. You can of course replace `ndgrid` by two `for` loops to increase memory efficiency, and quit early if an element is missing in the other array to increase time efficiency

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I'm afraid the object sizes in my application render the resulting permutation space too large to be practically searchable. Additionally, only some of the fields contained in my structs are order-agnostic. So I'd have to perform the permutations selectively, which I wouldn't know how to do for varying degrees of nesting.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If you say `isequal` works except for order, my approach using `isequal` should also work, nesting and all, right? I'm thinking something like <see next comment>. Anyway, if the product of sizes it too large to try all pairs of elements that would not be practical

Comment: (https://tio.run/##jVLBTsMwDL3nK3xBS0WH1o1TKz6Ab6h6cDKXRaQJpCkIpvHrxam0bgUOWFWT@vnFL371OuIbjWM7OB2NdxCoH2yEBzA9vQ5otxJzUJkw7Tkje/NJErMcpo3KMgEcMzGGgSq4gdYHcP79Dh4jdObpEEGR9h1Bi7aniZNKDDKnKN3QkeVTp/yMqStMXbAU@qJRojRJj5KG1VSLMtatF4kUKhA@s8RIoTMOI4FxjgJY71@AMNiPknWt4wHIUkcuMg7I7dKqFseR24u/9tz3Sy9a@CH@q4Xz8XebebrT8JZXnG7zS0Ra6Tzon/QJdHvWl95n84VIXhzr7Qb42W2aHFao9CrnXAHbpoJ6V943p1MlkjFYgToy/7Y48VfdVELMhuTAVl7/Qii5slwXZZEtgRoBm@yayUaP4zc)

Comment: `isempty(setdiff(a,b))` won't work?

Comment: To expand on beaker's comment: MATLAB does sets using functions such as `setdiff`, `ismember`, `intersect`, `union`, etc. But I don't know if these functions work with non-sortable values, or even if they work with non-numeric matrices.

Comment: Please give an example for what your data looks like! I'm curious what this "non-trivially nested inside the structs" is. Can you compute hash values for your objects?

Comment: @LuisMendo Well, the problem is that only some fields in the structs are supposed to be order-agnostic. Some other fields are not, and I don't see any way to differentiate between them in your approach. But anyways, as I said, the search space size would be unpractical.

Comment: @beaker Using this sort of manual equality check would require me to check the equality of the unsorted fields separately from the isequal on the surrounding structure. The isequal would still fail and I would have to check the equality of all other struct fields manually (which would be a pain).

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've already played around with the set functions, but they don't work with non-numerical values, because they use the MATLAB sort function internally. I've also thought of using hash functions to solve this problem, but the objects contained in these fields come from an external blackbox library and I don't have all the relevant information on their structure. Honestly, I wonder how the isequal can even work on those objects, but it does. I'm currently out of house, but will gladly provide additional details on the nature of my problem in a later edit.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've just found a very simple solution to my problem, see my answer below. I'll thus spare you with the cumbersome specifics of my data architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to solve my problem elegantly. Contrary to my previously stated belief, MATLAB actually does allow for class-specific overriding of `isequal`.

```
classdef CustomType
    properties
        value
    end

    methods
        function self = CustomType(value)
            self.value = value;
        end

        function equal = isequal(self, other)
            if not(isa(other, 'CustomType'))
                equal = false;
                return;
            end

            % implement custom comparison rules here
        end
    end
end
```

So, I can simply assign the fields in question like this and don't have to change anything else in my code:

```
a = Set([x y z]); % custom type
...
b = Set([x z y]);
...
isequal(a, b); % true
```

In my use case, I don't even need the uniqueness property of sets. So I only have to perform order-independent comparison and don't need to waste performance on ensuring unrequired properties. Furthermore, by using a dedicated type, I can differentiate explicitly between fields which have order (i.e. regular arrays) and those which don't, at the moment of assignment.

Another solution might be to overwrite the inbuilt `isequal` and make it apply custom comparison rules when its arguments are of specific type. However, this would slow down all comparisons in the whole program and make for bad encapsulation. I feel like using a custom type with an overriden `isequal` is **the** way to solve this kind of problem. But I still think that sets (and other types of commonly used containers) should be included in the basic repertoire of MATLAB.